# check sparsity of a term in {tm} R package

Tags: r, tm

This is a fairly specific question, but hopefully it's relevant to someone else too...

Does anyone know if there's a simple way to find the number of documents that a term appears in in a corpus with the {tm} package?

Basically, if I have a Term-Document Matrix that I've constructed, I want to see how sparse the row is for a specific term, i.e. how many columns in the matrix have a non-zero value for that row. A for loop could work obviously, but I'm working with a very large matrix so subsetting it repeatedly in a loop gets tiresome for the CPU.

Actually... (an answer to the above question would be great, but) what I'm really trying to do is get that number for *each* term in the matrix. Right now I'm using:

```
TDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(somecorpus)

terms <- TDM$dimnames$Terms

idf <- data.frame(term = terms, freq = numeric(length(terms)), stringsAsFactors = F)

for (i in 1:nrow(idf)) {
  aa <- as.matrix(TDM[,idf$term[i]])
  idf$freq[i] <- length(aa[aa[,1]>0, ])
}
```

That works, but it takes a *looong* time. Any better thoughts?
Thanks in advance,
Seth

Comment: Using `apply` should be faster than a `for` loop. Maybe try something like `apply(idf, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) {sum(ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0))})` and see if that's faster.

Comment: But it would be easier to help if you provided a sample corpus. Maybe the first 10 or 20 documents using `dput()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I figured it out! TDM's are stored as a sparse matrix, so you can just make a frequency table of the column for the terms. That at least gives you a count of each index, then you just have to match the indices up with terms.

```
tc <- as.data.frame(table(TDM$i))
```

Thanks everyone who looked at this. Hopefully it will be helpful to someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a quantity known as *document frequency*: the number of documents in which a term appears.  The easiest way to do this is to get the sum of the non-zero cells across the dimension for which the terms occur in the term-document matrix are defined.  (I put it this way since terms will be columns if you form this as a document-term matrix, which is the better method!)

You can get even faster results than with using `apply()` or `as.data.frame()` by using `rowSums()`:

```
require(tm)
data(crude)
TDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)
dfreq1 <- rowSums(as.matrix(TDM > 0))
head(dfreq1, 10)
##   ...      "(it)    "demand "expansion       "for    "growth        "if 
##     2          1          1          1          1          1          1 
##   "is       "may      "none 
##     2          1          2
```

The **quanteda** text analysis package has a built-in function for this, called `docfreq()`, that is even easier and faster:

```
require(quanteda)
DFM <- dfm(corpus(crude), verbose = FALSE)
head(docfreq(DFM), 10)           
## diamond  shamrock      corp      said      that effective     today        it 
##       1         1         2        20        11         4         7        13 
##     had       cut 
##       4         3
```

Note that `dfm()` applies punctuation and number removal, and lowercases the texts, which for simplicity I did not apply in the **tm** example above.